# MongoDB nodejs hook before write operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am using the mongodb driver for nodejs and i want to add last_update field on all my collections , i want when ever  there is a write operation to set new date on that field.

i am using my own package to warp mongoDB driver so replacing native function is an option.

i have tried find in google if there a hook before write but didn't find anything,
i thought to replace the update,updateMany,insert,insertMany but if there are more write functions i don't know a bout i will miss them , 
whats the best a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `Meta-programming` magic to achieve this. Check the code below and the repl [link](https://repl.it/@ShobhitChittora/proxy-mongo).

```
function collectionProxy(obj) {

    let handleInsertMany = function(list){
      return list.map((item) => ({...item, last_updated: Date.now()}))
    }

    let handler = {
        get(target, propKey) {
            return function (args) {
                // List all the update/ insert queries you want to use
                switch(propKey){
                  case 'insertMany':{
                        args = handleInsertMany(args);
                        break;
                  } 
                }
                let result = obj[propKey].apply(this, args);
                console.log(propKey + ' -> ' + JSON.stringify(args));
                return result;
            };
        },
        printArgs(args){
          args.forEach( arg => console.log)
        },
        handleInsertMany(list){

        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}

let collection = {
  insertMany(...list){
    return list;
  }
};


let proxy = collectionProxy(collection);
proxy.insertMany([{a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}]);
```

You can put this up as a JS module, initialize it once and export the new proxied collection.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem with this approach is the i need to do it on every write function. i am looking for something more global (for every write request)

Comment: I don't find any categorization of all type of updates. With the above approach you can keep a list of update methods you're using, and write the logic to add the `timestamp`. Also you can globally consume this proxy as a module and initialize it once before all the queries.

Answer (score 0):

found out that MongoDB has a [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/), so I use that for the hooks
also, i wrote a package [mongodb-data-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-data-sync)
that handles dependencies and set triggers using the change stream

Comment: The downside of this is, that you need a replica set/cluster. If not a big deal since you can have only a single node replica set but this feels some how wrong :/

Answer (score -5):

I think you should use **ORM** instead of **MongoDB driver** to manage all the CRUD operation. I would highly recommend **Mongoose ORM** out of all.
You can also create a schema for the collection.

Here are the examples to connect to MongoDB using mongoose:

```
const mongoose = = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/<db-name>');
mongoose.connection.on('open', (ref) => {
        Logger.info('Connected to mongo server.', ref);
        return db;
    });
    mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
        Logger.error('Could not connect to mongo server!');
        Logger.error(err);
    });
```

Example to create a schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongooseSchema = mongoose.Schema;
const ExampleSchema = new MongooseSchema({
            <field-name>: { type: String, default: 'field-name'},
        }, {
            timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
        });
mongoose.model('Example', ExampleSchema);
```

**Note:** Timestamp is the property which is automatically managed by mongoose to add the date in the field updated_at and created_at whenever a record is updated or inserted respectively.

You can also add hooks (pre, post). For example:

```
ExampleSchema.pre('save', <function to do some work>)
```

For more information refer to [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html).

Happy Coding!